# Avoiding multiple loops when checking cosine similarity across Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

The following is the sample data that I am having,

```
data['text']                          data['terms_counter']

This is a sample test                 {u'This': 1, u'is': 1, u'a': 1, u'sample': 1, , u'test': 1}
put returns between paragraphs        {u'put': 1, u'returns': 1, u'between': 1, u'paragraphs': 1}
for linebreak add 2 spaces at end     {u'for': 1, u'linebreak': 1, u'add': 1, u'2': 1, u'spaces': 1, u'at': 1, u'end': 1}
indent code by 4 spaces               {u'indent': 1, u'code': 1, u'by': 1, u'4': 1, u'spaces': 1}
to make links                         {u'to': 1, u'make': 1, u'links': 1}
```

I want to check the cosine similarity of each row with all the other rows append it to a dictionary and make it a column in the dataframe. The following is the output that I want,

```
data['text']                                 data['cosine_value']

This is a sample test                        {'put returns between paragraphs': 0.41, 'for linebreak add 2 spaces at end': 0.41, 'indent code by 4 spaces': 0.35, 'to make links': 0.41}
put returns between paragraphs               {'This is a sample test': 0.41, 'for linebreak add 2 spaces at end': 0.41, 'indent code by 4 spaces': 0.35, 'to make links': 0.41}
for linebreak add 2 spaces at end            {'This is a sample test': 0.41, 'put returns between paragraphs': 0.41, 'indent code by 4 spaces': 0.35, 'to make links': 0.41}
indent code by 4 spaces                      {'This is a sample test': 0.41, 'put returns between paragraphs': 0.41, 'for linebreak add 2 spaces at end': 0.35, 'to make links': 0.41}
to make links                                {'This is a sample test': 0.41, 'put returns between paragraphs': 0.41, 'for linebreak add 2 spaces at end': 0.35, 'put returns between paragraphs': 0.41}
```

I have tried the following code,

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    print i
    j_dict = {}
    for j in range(0,len(data)): 
        text= data['text'][j]
        if i != j:  
        x = get_cosine(data['terms_counter'][i], data['terms_counter'][j])
        if sni_name not in j_dict.keys() :
            j_dict[sni_name] = round(x,2)
#     print j_dict
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'text' : data['text'][i], 'similar_ones' : str(j_dict)}, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)
```

But the problem here is on my original data, there are millions of rows and this one is taking 15 mins for 10 rows. Can anybody help me in solving this problem ? I want a more efficient way to run this algorithm

The following are the ways which I am thinking we can solve the problem but I am not sure how to proceed,

1. kdtree implementation
2. Nearest neighbour

Can anybody give me any idea to solve this problem in a efficient manner?

Thanks

Comment: What is`get_cosine()`? Show that method or its library and why do you want a column of dictionaries?